# FBGraph and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

Hello and excuse me again

I have the next problem:

I am using fbgraph on ROR3. I understand that My application need permissions for to know about facebook user. So I need ask for permissions.

How could my application (facebook canvas) ask permissions from like button?

If need my code please to comment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about it, one of which is [the `FB.ui` route, using the "oauth" method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/). You wouldn't necessarily use it *directly* from a "Like", but rather as the result of a page refresh to a non-fan-gated page or specific user action.

Comment: Excuse me so i could make a popup with a iframe, for example, ask for permissions and then callback to another action which render presentation view

Comment: Yep! For example, you could just go back to the app's home page--now it might render differently since they've authorized the app and are a fan. Or it could go to a different page altogether :)